# Understanding JIRA dependencies and package imports

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I'm relatively new to JIRA plugin development and as I'm working through various tutorials I've run into a problem where I can only import certain JIRA java classes. For instance, when trying to compile this tutorial to create a custom search request view  https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/building-jira-add-ons/jira-plugins2-overview/jira-plugin-module-types/search-request-view-plugin-module I found that I can successfully import the following packages:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchException;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchRequest;
```

but cannot import these packages:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProvider;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProviderFactory;
```

Both SearchProvider and SearchProviderFactory are present in the javadocs for the latest version of JIRA, yet I can't import them despite them being in a package from which I've already imported.

Why is this? I suppose it's some sort of dependency issue but I can't seem to find a way to fix it. I'm developing in Eclipse, by the way.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in the generated pom.xml for JIRA plugin projects, the jira-core dependency is commented out. To access all developer classes, the following must be enabled.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```